# Multiple redirects with one domain on Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect one URL to one location:

```
http://mydomain.com/admin to http://mydomain.com/admin
```

And have all other requests from

```
http://mydomain.com point to http://myotherdomain.com
```

So essentially all other requests will redirect to myotherdomain.com except for http://mydomain.com/admin

I've tried setting up a Redirect rule in Apache but I'm not having any luck. I get a "The page isn't redirecting properly" message.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /opt/www/mydomain.com/
Redirect /admin http://mydomain.com/admin
Redirect / http://www.myotherdomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try (note the trailing slash):

```
Redirect /admin http://mydomain.com/admin/
```

Otherwise it would match `/admin` again in the `Redirect`, and get stuck in the loop you mentioned.

Alternatively, you could use `mod_rewrite` (untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://myotherdomain.com$1 [L]
```

(Apache will automatically redirect `http://mydomain.com/dir` to `http://mydomain.com/dir/` for any `dir`ectory, so you would just need to refine the `RewriteCond`.)